# Gtk3 move (child) window on wayland

Tags: gtk, gtk3, gtkmm, wayland

I use gtk3 and gtkmm. I want to move a window on wayland.

Hoever it doesn't seem to be possible. I tried using `Gtk::Window::move` method and `Gdk::Window::move` method. I also set `type_hint` on `Gtk::Window` and called `Gtk::Window::set_transient_for`. None of these worked on wayland, it just doesn't move. And also calling `Gtk::Window::set_transient_for` on the "child-window" makes my `TYPE_HINT_DIALOG` "child-window" not stay above the main-window anymore, which worked before calling this method.

I read however *this* in the *[gtkmm: Gdk::Window Class Reference](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGdk_1_1Window.html#abdaf2a58abef5b8bc4f7a36d7109076e)*:

> For toplevel windows, window managers may ignore or modify the move; you should probably use `gtk_window_move()`<sup>1</sup> on a Gtk::Window widget anyway, instead of using GDK functions. **For child windows, the move will reliably succeed**

It says moving child windows works. But I doen't know exaclty what it means by "child windows".

Now I want to know:

1. Is this true?
2. How can I make a certain window a child-window of another window in order to move the child window (and is `Gtk::Window::set_transient_for` the way to go)?
3. Can I somehow yet move (toplevel) windows with gtk on wayland (with e.g. subsurface or something else)

Note: C-code (gtk-code) is also welcome!

**Edit**: Just want to note: With Qt5 using app-option "-platform wayland" it's the same. Qt5 doesn't move windows when using wayland.

---

<sup>1</sup> I guess this is an error and it should be `Gtk::Window::move(int x, int y)`

Comment: Well, have you tried it and what happens? Questions like this get downvotes pretty quick.

Comment: @theGtknerd thanks for this tip, I added what I tried so far.

Comment: Could you try a different window manager? I assume this is the problem. If you post an MCVE, I could see if I can duplicate your problem.

Comment: @theGtknerd you are right, with Xorg it works. However I'd also like to get it working with wayland. I guess with gnome3 there might be many people using wayland.

Comment: Are you using the same window manager, but switching between Wayland and Xorg? In that case, I would file a bug on Bugzilla.